# How to list all firebase functions configs that are currently saved?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Is there any way to list all the keys that I saved using the following command to check for the ones that I want to remove in case of any issue or just for reference ?

```
firebase functions:config:set
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#retrieve_current_environment_configuration):

> To inspect what's currently stored in environment config for your project, you can use `firebase functions:config:get`.